# LaunchAgents runs Python script in version 2

Tags: launchd, python, path

Maybe someone can explain this. I'm having LaunchAgents run a Python script on startup. The relevant part of the plist looks like:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>python</string>
    <string>/Volumes/path to script
```

This launches the script in python2, despite the fact that "python" points to python3:

```
/usr/local/bin/python -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8
```

…which errors because launchd is running a python3 script in python2. To fix it I had to specify python3:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>python3</string>
    <string>/Volumes/
```

Am I doing this right? Is python2 coded into launchd somewhere? Is there a reason I still need to specify python3?

Comment: You should be specifying 'python3' anyway.  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use full paths in the XML, e.g.:

```
<string>/usr/local/bin/python</string>
```

launchd isn't aware of environmental variables, like $`PATH`, unless explicitly set in the XML, so `python` would default to `/usr/bin/python`.

https://serverfault.com/questions/111391/use-an-environment-variable-in-a-launchd-script

Comment: If launchd isn't aware of the `PATH` variable, how does it know the path to the "default" python  - `/usr/bin/python`